# How can i get the value from one method to another if the method is in void type in android

Tags: android

In this I need "**editTextUserName**" to another class or an another page.Inside the **Void Login()** method how can i get the value.Please Help me.

```
public void signIn(View v)
{
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.login);
    dialog.setTitle("Login");

    final  EditText editTextUserName=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.username_txt);
    final  EditText editTextPassword=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.login_password);
    Button DlgBtnSignIn=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonSignIn);
    DlgBtnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                                       public void onClick(View v)
                                       {
                                           String username=editTextUserName.getText().toString();
                                           String password=editTextPassword.getText().toString();
                                           String storedPassword=loginDataBaseAdapter.getSinlgeEntry(username);
                                           if(password.equals(storedPassword))
                                           {
                                               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Congrats: Login Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                               dialog.dismiss();

                                               Login();
                                           }
                                           else
                                           {
                                               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User Name or Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                           }
                                       }


                                    }
    );
    dialog.show();

}
public void signUp(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SignUp.class);
    startActivity(intent);

    // Do something in response to button
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // Close The Database
    loginDataBaseAdapter.close();
}
public void Login()
{
    Intent i= new Intent(this,user_page.class);
    startActivity(i);

}
```

Comment: you can use eventbus for passing data between not connected classes.
use the following library for android http://square.github.io/otto/

Comment: i just need to add the library.

Comment: Persist the value in Shared preference or SQLlite DB and access anywhere within your application.

Comment: pass the value as method as signature.

Comment: After logging in , I have page named user page,There i need to greet as welcome User.User value i need to get from the edittextusername.Please help me

Comment: check this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm

Comment: Hey, Not that.I need to return this value to another class.Can you please give an example

Comment: Hey..anyone please give example.

Comment: Guys i got the answer.Just need to declare as public and pass using intent.putExtra..